# Invalid length parameter passed to SUBSTRING function

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures

Having a bit of a run in with SQL and Transactions... hoping some of you can shine a light on the problem. (and maybe even fix my screwed html! Does this site support formatting for different languages? Perl, SQL, Java?) This server runs on SQL Server 2005 and was very recently upgraded from SQL Server 2000. I'll keep an eye on this post throughout the day. Cheers

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_AddRequest] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Message TEXT,
    @RequestId VARCHAR(20),
    @StatusCode CHAR(1),
    @StatusText VARCHAR(255),
    @AddedDate DATETIME,
    @MessageTimestamp DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Direction is incoming (i.e. Client -> WEBAPP)
    DECLARE @Direction VARCHAR(50)
    SET @Direction = 'Client -> WEBAPP'

    -- Type is derived from:
    -- a) MessageType Element value OR
    -- b) Data Element first child OR
    -- c) Root Element name
    DECLARE @Type VARCHAR(50)
    SELECT @Type = dbo.fnGetValue('MessageType', @Message)
    IF @Type IS NULL SELECT @Type = dbo.fnGetFirstChild('Data', @Message)
    IF @Type IS NULL SELECT @Type = dbo.fnGetFirstChild(NULL, @Message) 

    -- MessageStatus is retrieved from the lookup table
    DECLARE @Status VARCHAR(50)
    SELECT @Status = Description FROM MessageStatus WHERE MessageStatusCode = @StatusCode

    -- Examine the Message root element
    IF dbo.fnGetFirstChild(NULL, @Message) = 'RequestMessage'
    BEGIN
        -- Insert values into the Transaction table
        INSERT INTO tblTransaction (RequestID, Direction, [Type], Status, StatusText, Sent, Received, Body)
        VALUES (@RequestId, @Direction, @Type, @Status, @StatusText, @MessageTimestamp, @AddedDate, @Message)
        RETURN @@IDENTITY
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        -- Transaction is linked using the RequestId
        DECLARE @TransactionID INT
        SELECT @TransactionID = dbo.fnFindTransaction(@RequestId)

        -- Insert values into the RelatedMessage table
        INSERT INTO tblRelatedMessage (TransactionID, RequestID, Direction, [Type], Status, StatusText, Sent, Received, Body)
        VALUES (@TransactionID, @RequestId, @Direction, @Type, @Status, @StatusText, @MessageTimestamp, @AddedDate, @Message)
        RETURN @@IDENTITY
    END
END
```

Regards,

Comment: I don't see any `SUBSTRING` function here.

Answer (score 1):

Your substring must be in one the functions eg fnGetValue or fnGetFirstChild

Assuming it is, you can generate the same error by passing a negative number to the length parameter. Passing NULL or 'bob' or 2 billion or float: it either works or gives a different error.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING ('ffggg', 1, -1)

Msg 536, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the substring function.
```

Another point: don't use @@IDENTITY. Ever. Use SCOPE_IDENTITY().

Comment: Another catch - don't prefix your stored procedures with 'sp_' : from Books Online for 2005 (similar applies to 2000): "We recommend that you do not create any stored procedures using sp_ as a prefix. SQL Server uses the sp_ prefix to designate system stored procedures. The name you choose may conflict with some future system procedure. If your application uses nonschema qualified name references and your own procedure name conflicts with a system procedure name, your application will break because the name binds to the system procedure, not your own."

Answer (score 0):

You had a missing end quote here (after WEBAPP):

```
 SET @Direction = 'Client -> WEBAPP'
```

(which I fixed in the listing) but I couldn't find any reference to a SUBSTRING ........ what is the problem, really?

Marc